# Poor performance of sort by timestamp with limit query

Tags: sql, mysql, indexing

I have a simple MySQL table which consists of a primary key `id` field, a `time` (integer) field, and a foreign key ID field (`device_id`). There are indexes on each of these columns:

```
mysql> show indexes from device_heartbeats;
+-------------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table             | Non_unique | Key_name   | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| device_heartbeats |          0 | PRIMARY    |            1 | id          | A         |     2603552 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| device_heartbeats |          1 | IDX...bb8c |            1 | time        | A         |     1573451 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| device_heartbeats |          1 | FKb...xi10 |            1 | device_id   | A         |          16 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

The table currently contains about 2.6 million records. Here is the count for each device:

```
mysql> select device_id, count(device_id) from device_heartbeats group by device_id;
+-----------+------------------+
| device_id | count(device_id) |
+-----------+------------------+
|         1 |           315833 |
|         2 |              589 |
|         3 |           851461 |
|         4 |             2115 |
|         5 |          1104668 |
|         6 |                6 |
|         7 |              409 |
|         8 |              783 |
|         9 |              778 |
|        10 |              772 |
|        11 |              211 |
|        12 |              333 |
|        13 |            57370 |
|        14 |            57121 |
|        15 |           217468 |
|        16 |               58 |
|        17 |               66 |
+-----------+------------------+
17 rows in set (0.26 sec)
```

I have a query that finds the most recent record using the `time` field for a particular `device_id` (850k matching records):

```
mysql> select * from device_heartbeats where device_id = 3 order by time desc limit 1;
+---------+------------+-----------+
| id      | time       | device_id |
+---------+------------+-----------+
| 2610040 | 1697068792 |         3 |
+---------+------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The performance of this query is good, however if I use another `device_id` (one with only about 2000 records) then the performance is poor:

```
mysql> select * from device_heartbeats where device_id = 4 order by time desc limit 1;
+-------+------------+-----------+
| id    | time       | device_id |
+-------+------------+-----------+
| 48451 | 1684888379 |         4 |
+-------+------------+-----------+
1 row in set (1.59 sec)
```

Here is the EXPLAIN for `device_id` 4 (poor performance):

```
mysql> explain select * from device_heartbeats where device_id = 4 order by time desc limit 1;

+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table             | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                            |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | device_heartbeats | NULL       | index | FKb...xi10    | IDX...bb8c | 4       | NULL |    4 |    23.96 | Using where; Backward index scan |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------------------------+
```

Here is the EXPLAIN for `device_id` 3 (good performance):

```
mysql> explain select * from device_heartbeats where device_id = 3 order by time desc limit 1;
+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table             | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | device_heartbeats | NULL       | index | FKb...xi10    | IDX...bb8c | 4       | NULL |    2 |    50.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
```

The performance is good for each `device_id` except for 4 and 5.

What is going on here, and how can I fix it so that the performance is always good?

Note that the timestamps are not guaranteed to be inserted in to the database in chronological order so I can't just sort by the auto-incrementing `id` field.

Comment: Try to optimize the table `OPTIMIZE TABLE table_name;`

Also add index on the time field.

Comment: @SenthilPNathan the table already has an index on the time field. OPTIMIZE TABLE did not improve performance.

Comment: is it a composite index? `CREATE INDEX idx_device_time ON device_heartbeats (device_id, time);`
You could try with force index. It works in some cases.
if not try Partitioning the table.

Comment: Could you show us what `explain analyze select * from device_heartbeats where device_id = 4 order by time desc limit 1` says?

Comment: Is a query like this faster: select  t1.id, t1.time, t1.device_id
from device_heartbeats t1
where t1.time = (select max(time) from device_heartbeats t2 where t1.device_id = t2.device_id)
and t1.device_id = 4
;

Comment: If `id` is AUTO_INCREMENT, use it istead of `time` in ORDER BY.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel That assumes 1) every row was inserted with the current time and 2) the time was not updated and 3) no rows were inserted with an out of sequence id. An auto incremented primary key is not a surrogate for ordering by time.

Comment: Please update your question with the EXPLAIN PLAN for a device where the performance is good

Comment: `explain analyze` provides more detailed information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The short answer

If you are only interested in the max `time` for a given `device_id`, then the lightest/fastest query is simply:

```
SELECT MAX(time) FROM device_heartbeats WHERE device_id = 3;
```

with a composite key added:

```
ALTER TABLE `device_heartbeats`
    DROP INDEX `idx_device_id`,
    ADD INDEX `idx_device_id_time` (`device_id`, `time`);
```

### The long answer

You have not included the EXPLAIN plan for these two queries but we can guess at what is happening with a reasonably high degree of certainty.

If you run your initial `GROUP BY` query with `EXPLAIN` you will see something like this:

```
+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+-----+---------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table             | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+-----+---------+----------+-------------+
| 1  | SIMPLE      | device_heartbeats |            | index | idx_device_id | idx_device_id | 1       |     | 2645572 | 100.00   | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+-----+---------+----------+-------------+
```

This is reasonably quick as the entire query is performed against the index.

With your current single column indices the optimizer is going to have to choose one of them. With your `order by time desc limit 1` it is highly likely that it is going to choose the index on `time`. This is a great choice if there is a recent row for the given `device_id`, but not so great if it has to scan a large portion of the index and fetch lots of rows.

If you run the `EXPLAIN` for your query for `device_id = 3`, you will probably see something like this:

```
+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+-----+------+----------+----------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table             | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra                            |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+-----+------+----------+----------------------------------+
| 1  | SIMPLE      | device_heartbeats |            | index | idx_device_id | idx_time | 8       |     | 8    | 11.70    | Using where; Backward index scan |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+-----+------+----------+----------------------------------+
```

You will probably see a very similar `EXPLAIN` for `device_id = 4`, maybe with a higher but grossly under-estimated row count. The `Backward index scan` is going backwards through the index on `time`, reading the corresponding rows from the clustered index (primary key), until it finds a row with `device_id = ?`. If all the rows for a given `device_id` are from a *"long time ago"*, it has to fetch a lot of rows. If there is a recent row, it does not have to go very far through the index before finding the first row for the given `device_id`.

You could force the use of the index on `device_id`:

```sql
EXPLAIN
SELECT *
FROM device_heartbeats FORCE INDEX (idx_device_id)
WHERE device_id = 3
ORDER BY time DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

```
/* Output for device_id = 3 */

+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table             | partitions | type | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref   | rows   | filtered | Extra          |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+----------------+
| 1  | SIMPLE      | device_heartbeats |            | ref  | idx_device_id | idx_device_id | 1       | const | 851461 | 100.00   | Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+----------------+

/* Output for `device_id = 4 */

+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+-------+------+----------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table             | partitions | type | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra          |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+-------+------+----------+----------------+
| 1  | SIMPLE      | device_heartbeats |            | ref  | idx_device_id | idx_device_id | 1       | const | 2115 | 100.00   | Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+-------+------+----------+----------------+
```

This will be much faster for `device_id = 4`, as it only has to `filesort` 2115 rows, but it will be relatively slow for `device_id = 4`, as it has to `filesort` 851461 rows.

If you add a composite index (as suggested by [Senthil P Nathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16792034/senthil-p-nathan) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77284793/poor-performance-of-sort-by-timestamp-with-limit-query#comment136248972_77284793)):

```sql
ALTER TABLE `device_heartbeats`
    DROP INDEX `idx_device_id`,
    ADD INDEX `idx_device_id_time` (`device_id`, `time`);
```

```
/* Output for device_id = 3 */

+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+------+----------------------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+----------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table             | partitions | type | possible_keys                    | key                | key_len | ref   | rows   | filtered | Extra                            |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+------+----------------------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+----------------------------------+
| 1  | SIMPLE      | device_heartbeats |            | ref  | idx_device_id,idx_device_id_time | idx_device_id_time | 1       | const | 529656 | 100.00   | Backward index scan; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+------+----------------------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+----------------------------------+

/* Output for device_id = 4 */

+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+------+----------------------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+----------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table             | partitions | type | possible_keys                    | key                | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra                            |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+------+----------------------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+----------------------------------+
| 1  | SIMPLE      | device_heartbeats |            | ref  | idx_device_id,idx_device_id_time | idx_device_id_time | 1       | const | 5232 | 100.00   | Backward index scan; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+------+----------------------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+----------------------------------+
```

Note the change from `Using where; Backward index scan` to `Backward index scan; Using index`.

Because these are now simple index lookups, they should return in < 1ms.

A slightly better option, assuming your table has just the three columns included in your question (`id`, `time`, `device_id`), is to remove the surrogate PK:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `device_heartbeats`
    DROP PRIMARY KEY,
    DROP INDEX `idx_device_id_time`,
    DROP COLUMN id,
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (`device_id`, `time`);
```

Comment: 1) `(device_id, time)` makes the index on `device_id` redundant, it should probably be dropped. Two indexes, `(device_id, time)` and `time`, cover all queries. 2) I would argue against removing the id primary key unless it can be shown that `(device_id, time)` is unique. `time` is in seconds which invites collisions. If `time` were changed to be a `datetime` I'd be more comfortable. Composite primary keys bring headaches.

Comment: I had tried the composite index, but I did not drop the `device_id` index. I didn't realise that it might not always choose the 'correct' index to use. Query is working well now.

Answer (score 2):

Sensor data is best done with the `PRIMARY KEY` **starting with** the `device_id`.  Start with the thorough discussion by @user1191247, and @Schwern.  Now, let me wrap them together with this add-on.

I agree with **getting rid of `id` altogether**.  **But if you cannot** trust the times to be unique for each device, then keep the auto_inc `id` and do this:

```
PRIMARY KEY(device_id, ts, id),
INDEX(id)   -- see note below
```

The PK gives you the "clustering" that benefits many likely queries for this kind of data.  And it does not really have any adverse impact on `INSERTs`, despite the inserts being very close to 'chronological'.

The `INDEX(id)` is all that is needed to **keep `AUTO_INCREMENT` happy**.

The recommended `SELECT MAX(ts) FROM device_heartbeats WHERE device_id = 3;` will touch **only one row**, taking only a few milliseconds, even if the necessary block(s) are not cached.  The index is "covering" (Explain's "Using index") and will not need any filesort.

Even this will be nearly instantaneous for getting other columns:

```
SELECT *
    FROM device_heartbeats
    WHERE device_id = 3
    ORDER BY ts DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

The **uneven distribution** of `device_id` values won't affect these particular queries.

If `id` is `AUTO_INCREMENT` *and* you don't explicitly set `id`, then it will stay unique.

**Clustering** means that rows you are likely to fetch at about the same time are "adjacent" to each other in the B+Tree.

In MySQL, the Primary Key is always **clustered** with the data in the same B+Tree; the order of the tree is defined by that clustered key.  Each secondary `INDEX` is in a separate B+Tree, together with a copy of the Primary Key -- clustered by secondary key c9lumn(s) + pk column(s).  So my recommendation is effectively these two B+Trees:

```
PRIMARY KEY(device_id, ts, id) -- plus all other columns of table
INDEX(id)                      -- plus device_`id`, `ts`
```

Your Comment asked **why not these twp B+Trees**:

```
primary key(id),       -- plus all other columns of table 
index(device_id, ts)   -- plus `id`
```

**Here's why**:

- When looking up row(s) from a table, the Optimizer will pick the best B+Tree to start with.  (It will choose between the two being discussed.)
- If *all* the columns needed for the query are in *that* B+%ree, the index is "covering". (`EXPLAIN` will say "Using index".)
- If it needs more columns (your case), then it starts with the `INDEX(device_id, ts [,id])`, then uses `id` to reach into the data's B+Tree to get other columns needed.  This extra hop is avoided in my case.  The extra lookup adds time.

**The + in B+Tree** means that each block (of 16KB -- about 100 rows is a convenient Rule of Thumb) is linked directly to the next and previous block.  This makes "range" scans efficient in `SELECTs`.

But doesn't this slow down **INSERTs** since you insert a new row every N seconds for each of M device_ids?  Not really.  There will be M "hot spots" where a new row is being inserted every N seconds.  The buffer_pool is happy to cache the M blocks.  With either indexing, there will be a block split every approximately N*M/100 rows inserted.  Furthermore, every secondary index will also have a row added, together with another split per N*M/100 rows.

(A side note:  If you plan to eventually **delete 'old' data**, I strongly recommend `PARTITION BY RANGE`.  See [*Partition*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) ).

Comment: 1) If you're going to keep `id`, why have a composite primary key that includes the `id`? 2) How is `id` kept unique? 3) What advantages does this have over `primary key(id)` and `index(device_id, ts)`? You mention clustering, could you provide more detail?

Comment: @Schwern - Lots more details added.

Comment: Thanks for that. If I understand... 1) The hope is it will be a covering index so all the data can be read directly from the index without having to also read the table. 2) `id` is not guaranteed to be unique. 3) A MySQL clustered index enforces the order of the rows in the table itself, by default this will be the primary key. `PRIMARY KEY(device_id, ts, ...)` ensures the data is ordered by device id then by ts making `where device_id = ? order by ts` very efficient.  I found [an article explaining MySQL clustering indexes](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-index/mysql-clustered-index/).

Comment: @Schwern - Yes, that is a nice, concise, article.  As for "keep the PK short", I say:  If no secondary keys, it does not matter; if one secondary, then it do space is saved; only if more than one secondary key is space saved -- even then it may not matter much.